# Symfony "spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given" when editing with form entity type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have two entities namely, `User` and `Role` which has a many to many relationship between them. I generated a CRUD and it worked fine but the `UserType` form renderd a select menu for choosing roles for a user. Because I needed check boxes insted of a dropdown i made following changes to my `UserType` class

**initial**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('address')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('nic')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('isActive')
            ->add('roles');
    }
```

**after change**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('address')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('nic')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('isActive')
            ->add('roles',EntityType::class, array('class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\Role',
                'multiple'=>true,
                'expanded'=>true,));
    }
```

This is where it all started. I can create a new user without any problem but when I try to edit

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string
>   given

Error appears without rendering the edit form.

**My attempts to resolve the issue**

The user entity is used for login my system therefor I return an array of roles belongs to the user.

```
    public function getRoles()
        {
            $role_data = $this->roles->toArray();
            $roles = array();

            foreach($role_data as $key=>$role)
            {
                $roles[] = $role->getName();
            }

            return $roles;
        }
```

I changed the above getter to simply return an object as follows

```
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }
```

Now User Create and Edit worked fine but my login is broken since `getRoles` is no more returning an array

What I really want is to render the `UserType` form with checkboxes for selecting roles but when I try to do that this happened. I tried to find a solution without any success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form entity type expects list of objects (role entities) as its value, but gets list of strings as `getRoles` method returns list of strings. You can't change `getRoles` method as it is part of security component. You can rename `roles` field to something else and have 2 methods getXXX to get list of roles entities and getRoles for security component.

Ex.:

**User**

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM...
     * ...
     */
    $sroles

    function getSroles()
    {
        return $this->sroles;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $role_data = $this->sroles->toArray();
        $roles = array();

        foreach($role_data as $key=>$role)
        {
            $roles[] = $role->getName();
        }

        return $roles;
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('address')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('nic')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('isActive')
            ->add('sroles',EntityType::class, array('class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\Role',
                'multiple'=>true,
                'expanded'=>true,));
    }
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly.. But I'm still failing to realize how the form worked initially even when the getter is returning an array

Comment: For a new user `getRoles` returns empty array, nothing. So there is nothing to process by form. That is why form worked for a new user.

Comment: I get that but the editing worked without any issue as well when I was using the UserType class with `->add('roles');`.How is it possible with the getter simply returning an array ?